# Missing APR on apache2 ./configure

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to build the latest stable version of apache2.

I downloaded the source and put APR & APR-util in the srclib folder, then changed directories to `./srclib/apr` and ran:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr
sudo make
sudo make install
```

This seemed to install APR ok, but when I run `./configure` from the `apr-util` directory, I receive the error:

```
configure: error: APR could not be located. Please use the --with-apr option.
```

Using `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-util --with-apr=/usr/local/apr`, the error becomes:

```
checking for APR... configure: error: the --with-apr parameter is incorrect.
It must specify an install prefix, a build directory, or an apr-config file.
```

Why can't it find APR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not advisable to put each tool in separate directory.
just try using `--prefix=/usr/local` for both APR & APR-Util.
or, if you must, use `--with-apr=/usr/local/apr/lib`

Comment: Mine reads `checking for APR... configure: error: the --with-apr parameter is incorrect. It must specify an install prefix, a build directory, or an apr-config file.` Then it works with `--prefix=/usr/local --with-apr=/usr/local`. The versions are: `apr-1.5.2` and `apr-util-1.5.4`.

Answer (score 2):

I installed APR and APR-UTIL on my Redhat

APR location: /usr/local/apr

Then

APR-UTIL install cmd:

1. ./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/
2. make
3. make install

Answer (score 1):

If you followed this tutorial:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html

```
# cd srclib/apr
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-httpd/
# make
# make install**
```

then you should go for

```
# cd ../apr-util
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apr-util-httpd/ --with-apr=/usr/local/apr-httpd/bin/apr-2-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps it will resolve everything

```
yum install gcc
yum install openssl-devel
yum install expat-devel
yum install pcre-devel

wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz .
wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.6.5.tar.gz .
wget https://downloads.apache.org//httpd/httpd-2.4.48.tar.gz .
httpd-2.4.46.tar.gz
```

Extract all of these files at `/opt/WebServer/`

```
mv apr-util-1.6.1 httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr-util
mv apr-1.6.5 httpd-2.4.46/srclib/apr
cd /opt/WebServer/httpd-2.4.46
./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --prefix=/opt/WebSever/
make
make install
```

WebServer will be installed at `/opt/WebSever/`

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if your current user doesn't have proper permission for the

> /usr/local/apr

directory.
Grant Read/Write permission for the above folder for the current user.